# Как отправить torrent файл в PyTelegramBotApi методом sendDocument

Tags: python, requests, telebot

Создаю сессию используя модуль requests:

```
self._session = requests.Session()
```

Получаю файл:

```
response = self._session.get(_url_download, headers=self._HEADERS, stream=True,
                                     params={'t': film_code})
```

Сохраняю файл локально:

```
with open(path, 'bw') as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
            f.write(chunk)
```

Отправляю файл:

```
torrent = open(torrent_path, 'rb')
         bot.send_document(call.from_user.id, torrent)
```

Как мне не сохранять файл локально, и сразу отправлять его в сообщении?
На бесплатном хостинге где расположен telegram bot, запрещено сохранять файлы.

Если сделать так:

```
bot.send_document(call.from_user.id, response.content)
```

То файл отправляется, без расширения и с названием document.
Какие могут быть пути решения данной проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

В итоге нашёл решение.
Оказалось проще чем я думал.
Если кому интересно:

```
file = BytesIO()
file.name = f'{filename}.torrent'
file.write(received_file)
file.seek(0, 0)
```

В результате отправки в sendDocument всё корректно отображается.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два способы отправить файл без сохранения на диске:

1. Отправить прямую ссылку на файл вместо дескриптора файла
2. Использовать StringIO, пример:

```
import io
file = io.BytesIO()
file.write(received_file) // пишем в виртуальный файл полученные по http данные
file.seek(0, 0) // перемещаем курсор на начало файла
bot.send_document(call.from_user.id, file, caption=file_name)
```

Ознакомьтесь с документацией Telegram, там есть все доступные параметры и они полностью совпадают с методами PyTelegramBotApi: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument

Comment: Не работает. Работает только с BytesIO()
Но всё равно при отправке файла, получается document без типа и названия.
Есть ли возможность задать тип?
Caption = это описание, на название файла не влияет.

Comment: @PavelEfimov думаю нужно попробовать передать имя аргументом thumb
Если не поможет посмотрите на вот это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002546/paperclip-renaming-stringio-txt-using-instance-write